# Any way to make div scroll in ipad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I have tried so many different things and I keep searching but I find nothing!

Help anyone?

Comment: Haven't actually messed around with this stuff myself, but if you're developing for mobile using jquery, you should really consider using this: http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: You want to scroll it via the UI, or programmaticaly?

Comment: +1 for great question!  Was just researching the same thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See if this helps, the guy says the div must have a fixed size:
http://uxebu.com/blog/2010/04/27/touchscroll-a-scrolling-layer-for-webkit-mobile/

If that's not what you are looking for, you might also check out jqtouch and things like this jqt.scroll extension:
(sorry, I can only post 1 link apparently, look for jqt.scroll.js on this site:
code.google.com/p/jqextensions/ )

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, I found another one which works great... but not for scrolling inside a div. I'm about to try that link you sent it sounds perfect for what I want to do.  ill let you know how that goes

Comment: `jqt.scroll.js` appears to be based on the iScroll code from Cubiq.org (see below).

Comment: Touchscroll worked well for me, described in that uxebu.com blog

Answer (score 30):

Css Solution

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Comment: While this does work, there is an issue with elements that are being absolutely positioned. For example, I have a tool tip inside of my container along with a few form elements. The tool tip hides underneath the form elements if you add -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch. Also, you might notice that certain elements can become invisible if they are positioned relatively inside your container. You can get around this by setting a 3d transform property, but you will still have issues with absolute positioning.

Comment: Absolutely beautifly. Make sure to use it with overflow: scroll;

Comment: Seems this has become an "unknown property" in latest version Chrome.. it is `-overflow-scrolling` now

Comment: After time has went by, this is the real answer now without any hack arounds.

Answer (score 27):

use TWO fingers on the div!!! That's it

Comment: It works but most users will never figure it out. Need to make let them know somehow...

Comment: Agreed.. I would never try to scroll w two fingers.

Answer (score 11):

iScroll: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Looks/Works just like the native controls that have one-finger scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

I've had great luck with this on all browsers and platforms - including iPad: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

But, really it is just fancy-ing up the basic `overflow: auto` effect on an element

Comment: On the iPad, this does not seem to show the scroll bars, and you still have to use 2 fingers. Is there a way to get it to show the scroll bars and have 1 finger scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

I had very unusual issue for iPhone 6 with scrolling container, which parent has max-height:100%; This style somehow was disabling the scrolling. When I change the parent container style to height: 100% it works, but the point was to preserve the max-height. 
So the fix was to add

`-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)`

Hope this is helpful, I lost entire afternoon fighting with it.